# Magento 2 - Check if user is loggen in header.html

Tags: customer, login, customer-account, session

I'm trying to create a piece of code to check if the customer is loggen in or not. I read not to use the objectmanager for that, but I don't know where to put which code.

What I need:

*if customer is logged in {
Go to my account
} else {
Login
}*

How can this be achieved?

I'm using Magento 2.2.6

Comment: where you want to check this? in controller ?

Comment: I need to do this in: app/design/frontend/theme/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if not solve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code as below:

```
protected $_custSession;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    .....
) {
    .....
    $this->_custSession = $session;
    .....
}

//later in your code you can use it as below

if ($this->_custSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    // if customer is logged in 
} else {
    // if customer is not logged in
}
```

Since you are asking your question in phtml you can use the below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer is logged in
}
else{
  //customer is not logged in
}
```

Comment: Great! It's working :) I don't know if this is the best and only method to use but it's working at my side.

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom helper in and can call in **app/design/frontend/theme/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml**

like below:

**$helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Header');**
and you can call like:

> $helper->isCustomerLoggedIn();

In **Vendor\Module\Helper\Header** Class you can make one method for check customer is logged in or not

```
                 <?php
                  namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

            class Header extends 
           \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
             {

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
        ) {

    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function isCustomerLoggedIn(){
    return $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn();
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Rutvee, I which file should I put which piece of code?

Comment: make one file Vendor\Module\Helper\Header with above code which answered by me

Comment: and check  in app/design/frontend/theme/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml using


 $helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Header');


$helper->isCustomerLoggedIn();

Comment: This same solution is posted all over the place and it simply does not work. No matter what, it returns as not logged in.